# Ошибка при createIndex elasticsearch используя ElasticsearchOperations

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Я использовал org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch версии 6.8, а для подключения использовал TransportClient. Затем решил обновиться до версии 7.6, и так как TransportClient является Deprecated, был вынужден использовать подключение к elastic через RestHighLevelClient. После этого после запуска появилась следующая ошибка:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference, but class was expected
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.createEntity(RequestConverters.java:689)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.createEntity(RequestConverters.java:684)
at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesRequestConverters.createIndex(IndicesRequestConverters.java:128)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1760)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1696)
at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(IndicesClient.java:191)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:1248)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:1256)
```

Она возникает на строчке создания index:
    elasticsearchOperations.deleteIndex(clazz);
    elasticsearchOperations.createIndex(clazz, loadFromFileSetting(pathSetting, someParams));

Использую следующий конфиг-класс для подключения:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.project.elastic.repository")
public class ElasticConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.elastic.url}")
    private String url;

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        return RestClients.create(ClientConfiguration.create(url)).rest();
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Описанная здесь проблема решена добавлением *implementation "org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-levell-client:7.6.2"* в gradle.build. После этого вам следует указать тип индекса как *_doc* и убедиться, что ваша версия java-клиента соответствует версии Elasticsearch.